# How to use awk to search for min and max values of column in certain files

Tags: bash, unix, scripting

I know that awk is helpful in trying to find certain things in columns in files, but I'm not sure how to use it to find the min and max values of a column in a group of files. Any advice? To be specific I have four files in a directory that I want to go through awk with.

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for the absolute maximum and minimum of column `N` over all the files, then you might use:

```
N=6
awk -v N=$N 'NR == 1 { min = max = $N }
                     { if ($N > max) max = $N; else if ($N < min) min = $N }
             END     { print min, max }' "$@"
```

You can change the column number using a command line option or by editing the script (crude, but effective — go with option handling), or any other method that takes your fancy.

If you want the maximum and minimum of column `N` for each file, then you have to detect new files, and you probably want to identify the files, too:

```
 awk -v N=$N 'FNR == 1 { if (NR != 1) print file, min, max; min = max = $N; file = FILENAME }
                       { if ($N > max) max = $N; else if ($N < min) min = $N }
              END      { print file, min, max }' "$@"
```

Comment: What does the $@ part of the first set of code signify exactly?

Comment: The `"$@"` is the list of arguments to the script — the names of the files to be processed.  It tacitly assumes that you're writing a script to do this job because you'll probably need to do it more than once.  Hence the discussion on how to change the column number via an argument to a script, too.  I was using `data.?` when I tested the code, which expanded to `data.1`, `data.2`, `data.3`, `data.4` — and I used a program to generate those files with multiple columns of random numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: it will give min and max in file with comma seperated.

simple:

```
awk 'BEGIN {max = 0} {if ($6>max) max=$6} END {print max}' yourfile.txt
```

or

```
awk 'BEGIN {min=1000000; max=0;}; { if($2<min && $2 != "") min = $2; if($2>max && $2 != "") max = $2; } END {print min, max}' file
```

or more awkish way:

```
awk 'NR==1 { max=$1 ; min=$1 }
     FNR==NR { if ($1>=max) max=$1 ; $1<=min?min=$1:0 ; next}
     { $2=($1-min)/(max-min) ; print }' file file
```

Comment: What exactly is the $2 signifying? Is that an example of a column it's going through, so column 2 as an example? And to be a bit more specific, I want only one min and max for the group as a whole, not a min and max for each individual file

Comment: `$2=($1-min)/(max-min) ; print` - do a normalisation to [0,1]  and print data.

Comment: Your first two scripts are making major assumptions about the ranges of the inputs.   It is best to avoid doing that.  Your last script seems to be doing something wholly unrelated to the requirements of the question.  The FNR==NR line is not clearly written.

Answer (score 1):

`sort` can do the sorting and you can pick up the first and last by any means, for example, with `awk`

```
sort -nk2 file{1..4} | awk 'NR==1{print "min:"$2} END{print "max:"$2}'
```

sorts numerically by the second field of files file1,file2,file3,file4 and print the min and max values.

Since you didn't provide any input files, here is a worked example, for the files

```
==> file_0 <==
23 29 84
15 58 19
81 17 48
15 36 49
91 26 89

==> file_1 <==
22 63 57
33 10 50
56 85 4
10 63 1
72 10 48

==> file_2 <==
25 67 89
75 72 90
92 37 89
77 32 19
99 16 70

==> file_3 <==
50 93 71
10 20 55
70 7 51
19 27 63
44 3 46
```

if you run the script, now with a variable column number `n`

```
n=1; sort -k${n}n file_{0..3} | 
awk -v n=$n 'NR==1{print "min ("n"):",$n} END{print "max ("n"):",$n}'
```

you'll get

```
min (1): 10
max (1): 99
```

and for the other values of `n`

```
n=2; sort ...

min (2): 3
max (2): 93

n=3; sort ...

min (3): 1
max (3): 90
```

Comment: Just to be sure, with the first part of that command, to write it correctly it would be sort -nk2 Node1.txt Node2.txt Node3.txt Node4.txt ? Those are the names of the text files I'm using for this script, so I would just have to list them like that? No commas but just spaces in between each?

Comment: yes you can do that or you can write `Node{1..4}.txt` as well.

Comment: Also, if your delimiter is not white space you need to set it for both `sort` and `awk`

Comment: This almost worked, however it is giving me the min and max of every column across the four files, when I only want the min and max for one column. How would I fix that?

Comment: Also, the column to find the min and max with is based on the user input earlier in my script, so how would that work when using this code of yours?

Comment: you need to provide the delimiter, the default is white space.